# How do I link project to an svn repository?

Tags: svn

I've set up `svn` `/home/svn/repository/project` and created trunk, branch and tags under `/tmp/svn-structure-template`.

I have a project `/home/project`. How do I link it to repository, trunk and branch?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: A quick Google search on "SVN Tutorial" turns up tons on this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Initial setup of a new project is typically done the below way

Variant "a" (remote mkdir)

1. svnadmin create /path/to/repo
2. svn mkdir -m 'initial setup' file:///path/to/repo/trunk
3. svn mkdir -m 'initial setup' file:///path/to/repo/branches
4. svn mkdir -m 'initial setup' file:///path/to/repo/tags
5. cd /my/working/area && svn co -depth infinity file:///path/to/repo/trunk
6. cd trunk
7. enjoy the result

Variant "b" (local mkdir)

1. svnadmin create /path/to/repo
2. cd /my/working/area && svn co -depth infinity file:///path/to/repo
3. cd repo
4. svn mkdir trunk tags branches
5. svn commit -m 'initial setup'
6. cd trunk
7. enjoy the result

Once the working copy of the repository is created one can put new files/dirs to the working copy and add it to version control using "svn add" + "svn commit".

Alternatively one may use "svn import" to upload a directory tree directly to the repository under a specified url.

Comment: Step 8. Copy your files into trunk then add them to the repo using _svn add / svn commit_